# Laravel 6 The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, post, get, csrf

I try to create edit account user form. But i got an error with The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD notification. Here is my view blade:

**Blade.php**

```
<form action="{{ route('account_update.user') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $account->id }}" required>
  <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $account->name }}" required>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is my routes:

**Web.php**

```
Route::post('account/update', 'AccountController@account_update')->name('account_update.user');
```

And here is my controller

**Controller.php**

```
public function account_update(Request $request)
{
 DB::table('users')->where('id',$request->id)->update([
   'name' => $request->name
   ]);
 return redirect()->route('account.user');
}
```

Can anyone help me how to fix it?

Comment: do you have other routes for your AccountController? Maybe one of them conflicts with the one you show here.

Comment: can you share the error as well?

Comment: Just here : `Route::get('account', 'AccountController@account')->name('account.user'); Route::get('account/detail', 'AccountController@account_detail')->name('account_detail.user'); Route::get('account/edit', 'AccountController@account_edit')->name('account_edit.user'); Route::post('account/update', 'AccountController@account_update')->name('account_update.user'); Route::get('reset-password', 'AccountController@reset_password')->name('reset_password.user'); Route::post('reset-password/update', 'AccountController@reset_password_update')->name('reset_password_update.user');`

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
http://localhost:8000/user/account/edit`

Comment: I ran your code on my end, and it's working just fine. Check with the name of your controller and also see if you do not have this route duplicated.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi i have checked my controller much more but not find duplicated route, i make sure my controller name was fine, conflict? i have clear route cache with route:clear but produce nothing.

Comment: it's fix,the problem is i use double <form> :D

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use Like that
<form action="{{ url('account/update') }}" method="POST">
      @csrf
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $account->id }}" required>
      <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $account->name }}" required>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Change your url  then try

Route::post('update/account', 'AccountController@account_update');

Comment: or there may be a issue  in redirection  Please Check this route is post or get 

 return redirect()->route('account.user'); or return redirect()->url('/account');

Comment: I think Your route is wrong  , Check Your url

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. http://localhost:8000/user/account/edit

remove the user  because I  checked your route there is no user define in route

http://localhost:8000/account/edit

Comment: i use route namespace before.. `Route::namespace('User')->group(function (){`

Comment: <form action="{{ url('account/update') }}" method="POST">

      @csrf

      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $account->id }}" required>

      <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $account->name }}" required>

      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
Then use like that . You are not using the name space

Comment: it's work with url {{ url('user/account/update') }} thanks dude

Comment: Hi dude mark it right answer then other people  also get help from that Thanks